# No networks shown Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

I've been Googling this for hours and nothing out there has done anything to help me.

I'm on a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. My wifi adapter is detected but it's unable to find any networks. Sometimes a random network from a neighbour will briefly show up but then disappears moments later.

I've tried `sudo service network-manager restart`, uninstalling drivers, installing new drivers, everything I can find and nothing changes.

`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: wlp10s0
       version: 03
       serial: c0:25:e9:cc:06:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:ef400000-ef407fff memory:ef200000-ef3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: e0:d5:5e:29:b5:12
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:141 memory:ef600000-ef61ffff
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep wl`:

```
[   11.894798] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   11.894801] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   11.895961] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.961398] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   12.218254] wl 0000:0a:00.0 wlp10s0: renamed from wlan0
[  271.002236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp10s0: link becomes ready
[  417.453575] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 
[  417.453583] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power :
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: This new `[14e4:0619]` adapter must be poorly supported by Broadcom proprietary drivers. You can complain to Broadcom.